# Disabled Azure Functions still running

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am just starting to test with Microsoft Azure Functions. I have my VS2017 publishing and my function is working nicely. I currently have one function that I am working with. It is set on a timer of every 5 minutes.

However, it appears that that function is executing even when I have it "disabled". This can be seen in the Monitor and in one of the systems that it is interacting with. The only way that I am able to stop it is to stop the overall function group. When I then start the function group, it starts the disabled function running every 5 minutes again.

Am I missing something? Does the disabling of an individual function have some other purpose?

How do I get an individual function within a function group to not execute on its defined schedule?

Thanks.

Comment: I may have figured this out on my own... it seems that the state of the function at the time that the function group is enable is the determiner. I may have had the function enabled when I last restarted the group and then disabled it. The last time that I started the group, with the function already disabled, it did not start the function. In fact an error message shows that indicates a problem with starting the function.

Answer (score 12):

What you are experiencing is an expected behavior though not an ideal one. It is a bug in the portal experience.

The Function runtime directly consumes metadata in the binary files of the pre-compiled functions. Here is sample of annotation for the disabled function.

`[TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *"), Disable()]`

This is the function.json generated by visual studio the above annotations.

```
{
"generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.MSBuild-1.0.2",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": true,
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\FunctionApp3.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionApp3.Function1.Run"
}
```

The function.json generated by the precompiled functions is consumed by the portal and that is what is shown in the portal. When you change the disabled state of the function in the portal the disabled property is changed in the function.json but it is not consumed by the functions runtime. Hence it continues to execute.

When you deploy it in disabled state, runtime is aware of it and honors it as expected.

I have opened this bug to fix the portal experience.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/1857

Comment: Thank you Naren... to be clear then, is there currently no way to control the disabled state in the portal? My goal is to be able to publish a function in a disabled state and then go to the portal to enable it. I have a number of Functions to create and I need to be able to enable/disable them as required, preferably without stopping the overall function group.

Comment: There are 2 ways you can disable a function created through pre-compiled assemblies.

1. Update the attribute in .cs file and re-publish the function. This will re-publish the function.
2. Add an array of functions to be monitored by runtime. Update it each time you want to disable/enable function. You can update host.json from function app settings. This will restart the host though. But it is done gracefully and managed by runtime.

"functions": ["QueueProcessor", "GitHubWebHook"]

there is more information here
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json

Answer (score 1):

Today, I got the same problem, and after to disable the function in Azure, I recommend you to restart the Function service. Because the Azure needs to refresh the metadata, and the restart is one of the solutions to accomplish it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've stopped and started the function app but the portal-disabled timer trigger based function is still firing.

Comment: @Dzejms, apparently sometimes this timer trigger doesn't work. We tried to contact Microsoft but they will investigate the problem.